# Python filter not working as expected?

Tags: python, filter

Why do the following two filter expressions return the same result?

```
A = [(1,(1,2,3))]
A1 = filter(lambda (a,b): b, A)
A2 = filter(lambda ab: ab, A)
A1 == A2
>>>> True
```

Comment: What did you expect? Both `(1,(1,2,3))` and `(1,2,3)` are True.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Both 1 and 2 are 'True', yet 1 == 2 is False. Also, neither of those values is exactly 'True'

Comment: Did you actually look up `filter` in the Python docs? To quote The Princess Bride, "you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means."

Comment: You're filtering a one-element list by testing the entire element and its second subtuple. Both these tuples are truthish and do not get the element removed. The single-element list is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` filters out arguments that when passed into the function, returns a `False`-ish value. Both `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, (1, 2, 3))` return `True` in a boolean context, and therefore remain in the returned list.

You want `map` instead.

```
A1 = map(lambda (a,b): b, A)
A2 = map(lambda ab: ab, A)
```

FYI, the follwing values are `False`-ish values, while everything else is `True`-ish:

```
0
None
False
''
[]
()
# and all other empty containers
```

Comment: I knew that there was something absolutely trivial that I was missing. I completely confused 'filter' for map!! What a waste of a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug.  `filter` takes elements where your function returns `True`-y values.

In the first case, you unpack the tuple as `1` and `(1,2,3)` and you look at the second one (`(1,2,3)`) -- It's true (non-empty), so `filter` returns the whole thing.

In the second case, you look at the tuple `(1,(1,2,3))`.  That's not empty either, so it returns the whole thing again.